# Youtube Api v3, category and country specifications

Tags: youtube-api

I am working with Youtube Api v3 and I am collecting some information about videos. More specifically, I am interested in the category and the country/region parameter. With video-list and videoType="movie" one can retrieve the categoryId of each video. How can we correspond each categoryId, which is a number, with the specified movie categoty, e.g Comedy. Also is it possible to retrieve the region that comes with each video?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [videoCategories->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list) do get category information with the id.

API doesn't expose region code for each video, though you can always [search->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) with filtering by [region](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#regionCode).

API exposes [video's associated location](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#recordingDetails.location) or [file's recording location](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#fileDetails.recordingLocation) if that's available.