# Find country of channel in youtube api v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

In v2 of the youtube api, I could get the country of a channel by getting it's user information (https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId) and looking at the [Location property](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3alocation). It seems like it doesn't exists in [v3 of the api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels).

Since I'm only interested in channels from a specific country, is there a way to know in which country a channel is in?

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround is using [guideCategories](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories).

You can [list guideCategories by region](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories/list).

Then in your [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) call you can plug that [category ids](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#categoryId).

Comment: I don't think this works because different regions have the same guideCategoryId

Comment: Old question, but it took me way more time than expected to get data from guideCategories. Please do notice that in order to work, channels->list should be invoked from Google APIs Explorer ( https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list) otherwise it always returns empty list result for filtering by (guided) category id.

Answer (score 2):

The `regionCode` parameter **DOES NOT** do what you're thinking :)
It just sends back videos that **ARE AVAILABLE** in that country, not the one **PUBLISHED** in the country.

Answer (score 1):

It appears V2 of the API has finally been shut down.

Has anyone managed to come up with a workaround for this since V3 of the API does not support it ?

I have read through the API docs and while there does appear to be fields available for this data (snippet.country) it doesn't seem to be populated in the vast majority of channels.

What I require is to find the general region (country) that the channel / Video is associated with. Nothing more fine grained than that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know country info of a channel where it is located , it can be get via channel list API by using following code you can get a channel's country if it has mentioned in its ABOUT Section .
`id = 'Enter_your_channel_id_here'
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,statistics&id=' +    str(id)
    channel_url = url + '&key=' + str(key)
    raw_json = requests.get(channel_url).text
    dataa = json.loads(raw_json)
    channel_country = dataa['items'][0]['snippet']['country']`

this code will return country code of a specific channel, and by doing some google research you can obtain country names easily for country code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110451/youtube-api-v3-category-and-country-specifications) suggests, do a `Search: list` and filter by region code.

Comment: If I set the channelId then it will ignore the region parameter. If I only set the region parameter then I'll have a huge list.

Comment: What is the nature of your application? Is it possible to page the data?

Comment: People submit videos (which they might not own), I need to make sure sure the channel of the videos are in a specific country. I can still use v2 but would like to use v3 of the api.