# How can I retrieve the country of a YouTube-channel using the YouTube API 3.0?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I need to analyze channels based on country. In the YouTube API 2.0, the country was listed in the channel feed (location-attribute). In 3.0, this attribute is gone.

Is there any hope of the location-attribute returning to the channel-feed (https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels/)? Is there any workaround to retrieve country information? I already tried a suggestion on SO about the GuideCategories, which are completely useless for my purposes. I need to match country data to individual channels, not find a list of channels in a certain country.

Also, is there any way to request this as a feature to Google?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find country of channel in youtube api v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416199/find-country-of-channel-in-youtube-api-v3)