# How to get region of YouTube channel for a user?

Tags: youtube-api

My web app generates video and uploads it to users channel using YouTube Data API v.3.

After a user authorizes my app via OAuth, a form asks for video title, description, tags and video category.

Available categories list depends on user/channel region, as far as I know, so I must offer a relevant individual list of categories to pick from. That means a new API request for every session. However the list could easily be cached my server side to reduce the number of YouTube API requests.

If only region code would be available after authorization.

How can I learn the region code of the YouTube channel a user selected when granting `youtube.upload` permission to my app?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a request about the channel's info.

Like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&id=<CHANNEL_ID>&fields=items(brandingSettings%2Fchannel%2Fcountry%2Csnippet(country%2Cdescription)%2CtopicDetails)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

and get the `country` result.

Example: here I'm requesting the country of the channel `Musicoterapia` - channel_id: **`UCf4iMeUCDs0NFkJI03aJSbQ`**:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&id=UCf4iMeUCDs0NFkJI03aJSbQ&fields=items(brandingSettings%2Fchannel%2Fcountry%2Csnippet(country%2Cdescription)%2CtopicDetails)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The results are:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "description": "Bienvenidos al canal de musicoterapia, en nuestro canal podrás encontrar música relajante para dormir, meditación, yoga, zen, spa, estudiar y concentrarse, ondas cerebrales, cuencos tibetanos, música chamánica, y mucho más.\n\nNo olvides suscribirte para estar al día de nuevas publicaciones.",
    "country": "ES"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

You can test this request [in the Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&id=UCf4iMeUCDs0NFkJI03aJSbQ&fields=items(brandingSettings%252Fchannel%252Fcountry%252Csnippet(country%252Cdescription)%252CtopicDetails)&_h=4&).

Notice here that the `country` code is `ES`.

---

Another channel example is: `Justin Johnson` - channel_id: **`UCzH2vVrSpjwHNM0U3jJM0lQ`**

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "description": "Justin Johnson : Official YouTube Channel\n\nLive Concert Footage, Interviews, Press, and Instrument Showcases.  How-To Workshops on Guitar, Lap Steel, Slide Guitar, and Roots Instruments.  \n\nBooking & Media Inquiries: Contact@JustinJohnsonLive.com",
    "country": "US"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

You can test this request in the YouTube official documentation - [channel.list demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22UCzH2vVrSpjwHNM0U3jJM0lQ%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22items(brandingSettings%2Fchannel%2Fcountry%2Csnippet(country%2Cdescription)%2CtopicDetails)%22%7D).

Notice here that the `country` code is `US`.

Once you have the `country` code, you can proceed as user [Mak suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56722497/4092887).

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround is using [guideCategories](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories).

You can [list guideCategories by region](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories/list).

Then in your [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) call you can plug that [category ids](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#categoryId).

[Find country of channel in youtube api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416199/find-country-of-channel-in-youtube-api-v3/19417749#19417749)

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear. I want to present user an individual relevant list of Categories to pick from — for a new video that will be uploaded to users' channel. Available categories vary for users from different countries. [videoCategories.list()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list) requires a `regionCode` parameter - a 2-letter country code.  How can I learn that code for a particular user after his/her authentication via OAuth2?